# Chess app for iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, games, iphone

I want to improve my chess skills with my iPhone 5s and iPad 3. There are too many chess apps on the App Store for me to test. My ideal app should be free, strong, offers suggestion, nice graphics, adjust level of play etc. The app must play strong chess otherwise I don't learn anything from my games.

Any suggestions? At least I can't find one now.

Comment: http://www.chess.com/forum/view/general/best-iphone-chess-apps

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12458/what-is-a-good-chess-app-for-an-iphone-4

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Chess Free](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/chess-free/id378161776?mt=8)  and [Chess *](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/chess-%2a/id311395856?mt=8) apps, both are free, compatible with iPhone 5S and iPad 3 and top in downloads.

If you want to learn about chess, there are some ebooks like [Learn Chess](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/chess-learn-chess/id305309870?mt=8) available in app store and you may also try [Chess - Play & Learn](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/chess-play-learn/id329218549?mt=8) which was developed for both iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 0):

### Stockfish Chess

I think [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/stockfish-chess/id305558605?l=en&mt=8) has a decent reputation. That's based on my perusal of reviews of chess apps some time ago.